# Get Lowest Value While Comparing a Different Column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, min

I'm trying compare the data in a table and output the lowest value of each type. I know there's a `MIN()` function in SQL, but it will only get the lowest value overall, which is not exactly I want.

I want to get the data of the whole row, whose value in *Column1* is the smallest foreach type.

This is how the table looks like:

```
Type        Column1         Column2
-------     --------        ---------
A           1               !!!
A           2               @@@
B           3               ###
B           4               $$$
C           5               %%%
C           6               ^^^
```

When I use the `SELECT MIN(Value)`, the result I got looks like this:

```
Type        Column1         Column2
-------     --------        ---------
A           1               !!!
```

I used the `GROUP BY` method suggest by Linger, but the result still didn't quite match what I want:

```
Type        Column1         Column2
-------     --------        ---------
A           1               @@@
B           3               $$$
C           5               ^^^
```

However, the desire result is suppose to be:

```
Type        Column1         Column2
-------     --------        ---------
A           1               !!!
B           3               ###
C           5               %%%
```

How would I write my SQL query to do the job? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a simple query to perform simply by using the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT MTM.* FROM 
(
    SELECT MTS.Type, MIN(MTS.Values) AS SmallestValue
    FROM  MyTable AS MTS
    GROUP BY MTS.Type
) AS MainQ
INNER JOIN MyTable AS MTM 
ON MTM.UniqueID = MainQ.UniqueID
```

In the above example I am performing the `MIN() GROUP BY` query and then joining the results to the same table to pull the remaining fields I am in need of.  You should have a field that uniquely identifies a record.  Use that field instead of `UniqueID` above.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I guess I should've specify a bit more in my question. There are multiple columns in the table, and I actually want to get data for the whole row instead of just the min value. I tried GROUP BY,the MIN did display the min value, but other column doesn't match up. I'll edit my question

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to pull the remaining fields.

Comment: thanks! I ran the query and I realize another problem. there is no UniqueID (primary key) in the table. Not sure if it's possible to do the job then, or maybe ill just have to ask to re-design the db? thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: If you are practicing good design, then every table should have a field that uniquely identifies each row (primary key).  If you don't have that then using the above query there is no way to link the `MyTable` in the main query to the sub query.

Comment: the thing is, the database was designed by someone else. And I'm building on top of a query given by another person (which has inner joins and outer joins, looking into at least 4 different tables). The example I gave in my question is just the simplified form of what I can get so far. Plus I'm not too familiar with SQL, which is a bit challenging. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you can post the full query then I might be able to help you out further.